# How can I ssh into my home computer from the internet?

Tags: port-forwarding, nat, ssh-tunnel

Is there software that will help me to ssh/connect to my home computer from the public internet? (Say, a coffee shop).

I understand that questions similar to this have been asked, but none seem to actually answer the question. Let me add some details to avoid the usual slew of answers about DynDns and port forwarding.

- I have access to a publicly accessible SSH server. Merely port forwarding from there is not a stable solution that lasts several days. Port forwarding tends to drop connections, be slow etc.
- I dont want to setup/pay for DynDns and configure NAT traversal on my router.

I feel the following should be possible, I just dont know if there exists software that already accomplishes this:

Just the way peer-to-peer programs hole-punch NAT traversal, it should be possible to have a program running on my home machine that opens up external access to the appropriate ports by hole-punching. Further, the program can broadcast the home computers public IP and hole-punched externally visible port somewhere (say on a public server or over email) and periodically update this information.

Does software like this exist? A part of this functionality is already accomplished by various torrent software.

Comment: not sure what setup you are trying to avoid with DynDNS.  The free version available involved signing up with them, downloading an updating client, and then putting the signup email/password combo used into the client once.  You then have the address you signed up for to connect to the machine.  As far as port forwarding through your router... it's a relatively painless two step.  One... assign that computer a static IP in the DHCP reservation table, then forward port 22 to that IP.  Then, you just SSH from any computer to your address:22.  Not that bad, really.

Comment: In what way does (free) dynamic DNS and simple port forwarding not answer the question?

Comment: DynDNS is free, and many (most?) routers also have a built-in DynDNS client, so you don't even have to run it yourself. You could try using a reverse SSH tunnel to get around the NAT, but port forwarding is probably more reliable.

Comment: Could you please clarify: When being at the coffee shop, would you use your own device (e.g. laptop) to access the internet, or would you use the coffee shop's devices (if they provide such devices for public usage)?

Answer (score 0):

I do not suggest placing your device into a DMZ under any circumstance, unless you really know what you're doing and can properly secure the device and the network surrounding it.

There is software that can emulate a LAN through the internet, called *LogMeIn Hamachi*. By installing and enabling this on the host, you can access it by logging into the VLAN anywhere on the internet.

Although I don't necessarily see the problem with Port Forwarding.

Another option is to use SSH's built-in Port Forwarding feature. If there is another SSH host accessible from the internet (we'll call it Host 1) on the same LAN as the host you're trying to connect to (Host 2), you can issue a command that bounces the connection from your computer (on a specific local port) through Host 1, and Host 1 routes your traffic to the non-port-forwarded Host 2 in it's LAN.

The command is as follows and is to be executed on the local machine that you're trying to use to connect to Host 2

```
ssh -L [local-port-to-open]:[local-IP-of-Host-2-according-to-Host-1]:[port-to-connect-to-on-Host-2-from-Host-1] [user-of-Host-1]@[Host-1-address]
```

This will open a port on your machine (your `[local-port-to-open]` argument) that SSH manages, sending any traffic from that port through the encrypted tunnel made my the `[user-of-Host-1]@[Host-1-address]` arguments to Host-2 as specified in `[local-IP-of-Host-2-according-to-Host-1]:[port-to-connect-to-on-Host-2-from-Host-1]`. This method is called Local Port Forwarding (I don't really understand remote port forwarding).

For example, say I want to connect to Host 2, which is not port forwarded, from my local coffee shop, using Host 1, which is port forwarded, to bounce the connection into it's LAN. Note that this will open a PTS on the remote machine, but it can be ignored until you want to close this tunnel. Then you can just close that terminal session as you would normally.

Host 1's public IP is `201.31.103.212` (the NAT that encapsulates both Host 1 and Host 2) on port `1337` for SSH. Host 2, in the LAN, has the local IP of `192.168.254.40` and uses port `22` for SSH. Host 1's login username is `fish`.

Ok, so I'll just say that I have the local port `8080` unused and can use it for this demonstration temporarily.

The command I would form is as such:

```
ssh -L 8080:192.168.254.40:22 fish@201.31.103.212
```

Now that opens port `8080` on your local computer and sends to to `192.168.254.40` on port `22` (Host 2) according to Host 1 (which is `fish@201.31.103.212`)

Now if you want to SSH into Host 2, all you have to do is specify your computer on port `8080`. Let's say that Host 2's login username is `turtle`

```
ssh turtle@127.0.0.1 -p 8080
```

SSH is managing your port `8080`, and it sends your SSH request to Host 1, which sends it to Host 2. Please note that, as opposed to using `127.0.0.1`, you can also just use `localhost`. It's just preference.

Another use of SSH Port Forwarding is proxies.

Scenario: I'm at school with my personal laptop and want to access Twitter, which is blocked (it actually is at my high school, so I've done exactly this). I have a port-forwarded SSH host at my house with the IP `39.34.81.56` on port `1337`. I want to bounce a connection to Twitter (web servers are most commonly hosted on port `80`) from my port `8080` on my laptop through my host at home.
I would issue the command on my laptop:

```
ssh -L 8080:twitter.com:80 root@39.34.81.56 -p 1337
```

Now I can access `localhost:8080` in my web browser, and it will route Twitter through my encrypted tunnel, from their servers to my home then to my laptop at school.

I can use this same method to log into a website that does not use SSL (pastebin for example) in public and be sure that my credentials are safe because it's encrypted using SSH and only sent without SSH from my home, which I've made sure is secure.

Good luck!

EDIT: Just a side note, the IP addresses shown here should not be valid addresses, but on the off-chance that they are, please do not harass the users of these IPs.

Comment: The fragment about *LogMeIn Hamachi* may be improved by following [this general outline](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/432690).

Answer (score -1):

Ya so I think port forwarding IS the hole punching method.  If you wanted, you could put your computer in a DMZ and avoid all the mess.

Comment: I wouldn't put a computer permanently in a DMZ unless you REALLY know what you're doing with network security.

Comment: Port forwarding is something very different than hole-punching. There's not enough room to explain the basics here, though ...